# Add extra cost depending on length of path

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I have a graph/network that obviously consists of some nodes and some edges. Each edge has a weight attached to it, or in this case a cost. Each edge also have a distance attached to it AND a type. So basically the weight/cost is pre-calculated from the distance of the edge along with some other metrics for both type of edges.

However, in my case I would like there to be added some additional cost for let's say every 100 distance or so, but only for one type of edge.But I'm not even certain if it is possible to add additional cost/distance depending on the sum of the previous steps in the path in algorithms such as Dijkstra's ?

I know I could just divide the cost into each distance unit, and thus getting a somewhat estimate. The problem there would be the edge cases, where the cost would be almost double at distance 199 compared to adding the cost at exactly each 100 distance, i.e. adding cost at 100 and 200.

But maybe there are other ways to get around this ?

Comment: If your extra cost is always positive, and the same for every path,then the shortest path does not change when you add it on - since it is also added to the competing paths which are even longer and so incur the same or more extra costs  So just add the ectra costs to the path AFTER finding the shortest path.

Comment: Okay, I actually missed some crucial info in my OP (has been added now). But there is actually also a type associated with each edge. And it's only for one type that this additional cost should be added.

Comment: Now you are going to need an iterative approach.  Find shortest path.  Check for extra costs.  If none, stop.  Add extra costs to edge incurring them.  Repeat.

Comment: Arh, I actually just thought of a way. Since the one type, where this is supposed to be added, should always be the secondary choice (if possible), I can just give it an extra cost, so that it will always choose the other (cheaper) type, unless it really isn't possible, even though these extra cost is added. And then after the path is found, I can add whatever is needed to get the correct cost of the path.

Comment: @ravenspoint Your first comment is not true. Although the question was edited since you made your first comment, so maybe that's why. Imagine if I want to arrive to point C, and I already found a path of length 98 to point A. Now there are two ways to get from A to C: through edge AC with cost 3, or through edges AB (cost 1) and BC (cost 1). Dijkstra will say that going through AB-BC has a lower cost; but then we end up with a path of total length 100, and incur a penalty; whereas if we had taken edge AC, we wouldn't have incurred the penalty.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot implement this using Dijkstra, because you would validate the invariant, which is needed for correctness (see e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Proof_of_correctness)). In each step, Dijkstra builds on this invariant, which more or less states, that all "already found paths" are optimal, i.e. shortest. But to show that it does not hold in your case of "additional cost by edge type and covered distance", let's have a look at a counterexample:

### Counterexample against Usage of Dijkstra

Assume we have two types of edges, first type (->) and second type (=>). The second type has an additional cost of 10 after a total distance of 10. Now, we take the following graph, with the following edges

```
start -1-> u_1 
start -1-> u_2 
start -1-> u_3 
... 
start -1-> u_7 
u_7 -1-> v 
start =7=> v 
v =4=> end
```

When, we play that through with Dijkstra (I skip all intermediate steps) with `start` as start node and `end` as target, we will first retrieve the path `start=7=>v`. This path has a length of 7 and that is shorter than the "detour" `start-1->u_1-1->... -1->u_7->v`, which has a length of 8. However, in the next step, we have to choose the edge `v=4=>end`, which makes the first path to a total of 21 (11 original + 10 penalty). But the detour path becomes now shorter with a length of 12=8+4 (no penalty).

In short, Dijkstra is not applicable - even if you modify the algorithm to take the "already found path" into account for retrieving the cost of next edges.

### Alternative?

Maybe you can build your algorithm around a variant of Dijkstra, which usually retrieves multiple (suboptimal) solutions. First, you would need to extend Dijkstra, so that it takes the already found path into account. (In [this function](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/c47964d7ab849d143cd57607a2a6dbbb53bbaf30/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/weighted.py#L755) replace [`cost = weight(v, u, e)`](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/c47964d7ab849d143cd57607a2a6dbbb53bbaf30/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/weighted.py#L830) with `cost = weight(v, u, e, paths[v])` and write a suitable function to calculate the penalty based on the previous path and the considered edge). Afterwards, remove edges from your original optimal solution and iterate the procedure to find a new alternative shortest path. However, I see no easy way of selecting which edge to remove from the graph-beside those from your penalty type-and the runtime complexity is probably awful.

Comment: I think that’s not right since Dijkstra doesn’t stop when the goal is reached, but stops when the goal is reached AND closed (smallest element in queue). So, it will discover the shorter detour.